# how to change image src using props with styled component and react

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to reuse my component for multiple pages.
so, I have to change img src in styled.img component as passing props.

is it possible to change image src on styled component ?

I applied my code like below.
it's not working..

```
//logic

import Myimg from './img/icon_my';

const OngoingLists = ({ ...props }) => {
  return (
    <ListsOutWrap>
      <ProgramListWrap {...props}>
        <IconWrap {...props} >
          <MyIcon {...props} />
        </IconWrap>
      </<ProgramListWrap>
    </ListsOutWrap>
  );
}


// styled component 
const MyIcon = styled.img.attrs({
  src: props => props.Img || { Myimg },
})`
  width: 100%;
`;
```

I tried like above, any image doesn't show...even default img file doesn't show..
how can I change src file by using props ?? 
should I use background-image ?

thanks for ur help in advance ! :)

Comment: Did you mean `src: props => props.Img || Myimg`?

Comment: yes, I want to use Myimg as default props  and want to pass another img file as props.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Styled components are still just react components, and you can simply provide a default prop value in the case a `src` prop isn't passed when used.

```
import Myimg from './img/icon_my';

const MyIcon = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
`;

MyIcon.defaultProps = {
  src: Myimg,
};
```

Usage:

```
<MyIcon /> // uses default Myimg
<MyIcon src="/path/to/sourceImage" /> // uses "/path/to/sourceImage"
```

[image: Edit charming-sunset-fpd6c]

**BTW** Correct [`attrs`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs) format to accept props would be to define a function taking props and returning an object:

```
const MyIcon = styled.img.attrs(props => ({
  src: props.Img || Myimg,
}))`
  width: 100px;
`;
```

Comment: And what if I wanna change the image source depending of @media ?

Comment: @alerya I don't see a way to do that from a single styled component, but you could create a react component that manages several image components that display/hide themselves are certain media query breakpoints. It's a bit out-of-scope and rather a new question, so if you've a specific issue feel free to ask a new question and (at) me in a comment.