# Property 'src' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I cant show my Image because of this error on the src property, how do I declare this correctly?

```
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Product = ({item}:any) => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Circle/>
            <Image src={item.imagem}/>
            <Typography>
                {item.nome}
            </Typography>

        </Container>
    )
}

export default Product;``
```

Comment: use img tag instead of image

Comment: Same error, even if I change

Comment: I think its because of styled component , hope this linke is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60717004/how-to-change-image-src-using-props-with-styled-component-and-react

Comment: I tried this method and still didnt work with props.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`<Box component="img" src={item.imagem} />`